# Deleting a react component from component list deletes the other components in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-component

I have a list of components that are added upon button click, so every button click adds one of the components. Each component has a button that can be clicked to delete the component from the list.

[image: Example of how result looks like.]

Each pair of text "New Item" and button is created as one component in the insertNewCollectorFields function. This function is called when the maroon button is clicked. Each component is added to a list of components "collectorsList" to be displayed. For each component, I use the current length of this collectorsList as the id and key.

This is my code:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function Test(){
    const [collectorsList, setCollectorsList] = useState([])

    const insertNewCollectorFields = () => {
        setCollectorsList(collectorsList.concat(
            <div id={collectorsList.length} key={collectorsList.length}>
                <p>New Item</p>
                <button onClick={()=>deleteNewCollectorFields(collectorsList.length)}>Delete New Item</button>
            </div>
        ))
    }

    const deleteNewCollectorFields = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        setCollectorsList(collectorsList.filter((item) => item.id!==id))
    }

    return <div>
        {collectorsList}
        <button type={"button"} className={`btn col-auto maroonButton`} onClick={insertNewCollectorFields}>Add Another Collector</button>
   </div>
}
```

I am able to add the components, and I can delete components that were added last without an issue. However, if I delete one of the components that was added first, any component that was added after it is deleted too, and I don't understand why.

This is an example of the issue:
Here I add three components:

[image]

Now I delete that third component, and no issue:

[image]

If I however delete the first component, all three components disappear, and this is the issue:

[image]

I created the list of components as a state. This is my first big project using React. What I know is that on creating a state, the value is updated and should be seen by all the components with the updated value? But apparently on debugging, I found that the "collectorsList" seen by every component in the deleteNewCollectorFields function is limited to the list that was present before creating that component. For example, if collectorsList contained 6 components, component number 3 only sees that there is component 1 and 2 in the collectorsList, and does not see that the collectorsList actually contains 6 components. So on deleting component number 3, the filter process in the delete function results in only component 1 and 2, and everything else disappears from the screen.

I don't understand why this happens and why the components are not able to see the updated list with all the components that were added to it. I also searched for other examples were such a delete function was created and it seems that my method should work, and I couldn't find any case were this problem was faced.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I understood incorrectly about the use of states?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `id={collectorsList.length}`, which is wrong, because the `.length` is changing every time you delete an item and this give wrong id to the `deleteNewCollectorFields`, just make unique id

Comment: But why am I able to delete the items without deleting the ones before them? I mean, if I delete component 3 then components 1 and 2 also have the id={collectorsList.length}, but they are not deleted like the components that come after component 3?

Comment: I also printed the id of each component when I delete them, and each of them had a unique id even after adding new components.

Comment: when you have for ex:  3 comp the arr.length is 3 and when you delete comp with number 3 the all is ok, but when you delete 2nd component you pass to your delete function arr.length which is 3 and that will delete the component with id 3

Comment: and by this component 2 also gets deleted?

Comment: please excuse my many questions I'm just trying to understand 

Comment: more also you use also `.length` for key which is wrong ! And when you delete 1 item from the array the length is changing and thats why  all next item is deleted. Just make one variable `itemCounter = 1`  and use it like this in ids `id={itemCounter++}`