# Deleting a Component Removes all Components after it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs and React to create a form. I have an input box that gets created with a button click. There can be multiple input boxes. To delete the input box, you click the delete button next to it.

[image: Picture of inputs and buttons]

The issue is: if you click Delete on one row, it will delete that row and all the rows after it.

E.g. if you click delete on row 2, it will delete row 2 and three. if you click delete on row 1, it will delete all the rows. If there are 10 rows, and you delete row 4, there will only be 3 rows.

I saw a similar [similar Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961167/deleting-a-react-component-from-component-list-deletes-the-other-components-in-t) where it said to not use the length because the length kept changing but that does not seem to be the case here. I changed the ID to be a timestamp from `new Date.getTime()` .

Here's my parent component:

```
export default function CmdBuilder() {
  const [cmdNodes, setCmdNodes] = React.useState([]);

  function addRow() {
    setCmdNodes(
      cmdNodes.concat(
        <CmdNode key={new Date().getTime()} uniqueId={new Date().getTime()} onRemove={(id) => removeNode(id)} />
      ));
  }

  function removeNode(id) {
    setCmdNodes((nodes) => cmdNodes.filter((node) => node.uniqueId != id));
    );
  }

  return (
    <div id='cmdBuilder'>
      {cmdNodes}
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add Row</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my child component:

```
export default function CmdNode(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.builderGroup} id={props.uniqueId}>
      <input type='text' className={styles.cmdText} />
      <button className={styles.cmdDelete} onClick={() => props.onRemove(props.uniqueId)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What could I be missing? The logic seems right but please let me know if I'm missing something fundamental.

Edit: I've verified that the key and uniqueId values match, if that matters. I've also verified that the selected row's uniqueId is correct.

Comment: Don't put components in state! Put data in state and just render components based on the data.

Comment: should be `nodes.filter` instead of `cmdNodes.filter` for starters. both this question and the similar question you linked are simple logic errors, nothing to do with using length being "wrong"

Comment: and the "something fundamental" that you're missing is how closures work in javascript

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these issues. I'm open to learning and improving. Do you have any resources or something specific I can google to improve?

@SoZettaSho Thank you for the solution. If you want to add that, I can accept it. I'll be reading more on closures next. Is there a specific term or usage where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `removeNode` you are passing a function to `setState` which is fine. React will pass the component's current state as a parameter to this function. In your definition you have named this parameter `nodes`, but then you refer to `cmdNodes` in the function body instead of nodes. Simply change

```
(nodes) => cmdNodes.filter((node) => node.uniqueId != id)
```

to

```
(nodes) => nodes.filter((node) => node.uniqueId != id)
```

The first version doesn't work because the value of `cmdNodes` is bound to the [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) at the time when the function is defined; it's not actually deleting all the components after it, you're just accidentally resetting state to the value it had when `onRemove` was initialized.

You could probably just set the value of `setCmdNodes` as well. I haven't tested it but it would avoid some of this closure nonsense.

```
setCmdNodes(cmdNodes.filter((node) => node.uniqueId != id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put component instances in state, put data in state and render components:

```
function CmdBuilder() {
  const [cmdNodes, setCmdNodes] = React.useState([]);

  function addRow() {
    setCmdNodes((nodes) => [...nodes, { id: new Date().getTime() }]);
  }

  function removeNode(id) {
    setCmdNodes((nodes) => nodes.filter((node) => node.id !== id));
  }

  return (
    <div id="cmdBuilder">
      {cmdNodes.map(({ id }) => (
        <CmdNode key={id} uniqueId={id} onRemove={removeNode} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add Row</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function CmdNode(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.builderGroup} id={props.uniqueId}>
      <input type="text" className={styles.cmdText} />
      <button
        className={styles.cmdDelete}
        onClick={() => props.onRemove(props.uniqueId)}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You also had a typo where you weren't using `nodes` in `removeNode` – look for the unused variable low-lighting in your IDE to catch bugs of that sort.